# How to compare the values from the list to the table and fetch the result uisng MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

I created a function which will fetch all the values from the tables, then i want to know how to use that list and compare against another table(Transaction table) and fetch the result.

Method to fetch the divisions

---

```
*public List<object> _Listdiv(string contextType)
        {
    List<object> mylist = new List<object>();
    using (var context = this.dbContext.CreateContext(contextType)) 
        {
                string filter = "test";
                string Email = GlobalVariables.UserEmail;
                if (Email.Split('@')[1].Substring(0, 6) == "comp")
                {
                    filter = "comp";
                }
                var query = (from div in context.Divisions.Where(p => p.Company == filter)
                             select div.Code).ToList<object>();
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    mylist.Add(item);
                }
                return mylist;
            }
        }*
```

I am calling this in Action Result

---

```
*foreach (object item in mylist)
 {
test += item ;
context.SearchExtension.AddSearchExpression<Folder>(i => i.Divisions.Contains(test));
 }*

MyList values like -> TestA,TestB,TestC
```

**> How can I compare this without hardcoding like below ?**

```
*context.SearchExtension.AddSearchExpression<Folder>(i => i.Divisions.Contains("TestA") || i.Divisions.Contains("TestB") || i.Divisions.Contains("TestC"));*
```

I am not able to do this kindly help!!!! Much Appreciated!

Comment: `i.Divisions.Any(t=> myList.Contains(t));`

Comment: with the above solution I get error - DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
Parameter name: input

Comment: probably because you are using `object`. don't use `object` so much, you are creating a lot of boxing and unboxing. you are also creating a list and then recreating a list with the exact same data. Post the complete `Divisions` model and I will give you the linq query.

Comment: Divisions is a table from the first method which i posted :   [Table("tbl_Division")]
    public class Division : Entity
    {
        [Key, Column(TypeName="varchar"), MaxLength(20)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string DivisionName { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

       public string Company { get; set; }
    }

Comment: i.Divisions.Any(t=> myList.Contains(t)); --- > FolderModel - public string Divisions { get; set; }

Comment: In your folder model, divisions isn't a collection it is just a `string`. Making the name plural is misleading. `i=>mylist.Any(i.Divisions.Contains)`

Comment: yes its a string! is this your solution as i see its incomplete! -- i=>mylist.Any(i.Divisions.Contains)

Comment: any update please?

Comment: It's not incomplete, that's the solution. `i=>mylist.Any(i.Divisions.Contains)` is shorthand for `i=>mylist.Any(t=>i.Divisions.Contains(t))` but both produce the same compiled code.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have a scenario where  mylist contains DP(as one of the value) and Divisions contains DPT, the problem here is even though DPT is not part of the List it still shows up in the resultset. Currently the solution works fine apart from this scenario. how can i avoid this?

Comment: Does Divisions contain multiple divisions with a delimiter? What exactly is in the Divisions string?

Comment: yes divisions as values like -- DP,AB etc, we need that based on the mylist(if list contains DP and DP,AB we need that in the result set) but we dont need DPT as its not part of the list but part of Divisions(we dont need everything from divisions), All that is required is mylist with all combinations of values.

Comment: Ideally you would use some flavor of a collection instead of a delimited string. You can split the string and check it more efficiently or do something ugly and slow like this `i=>mylist.Any(t=>t == i.Divisions || i.Divisions.Contains(t + ",") || i.Divisions.EndsWith("," + t))`

Comment: Thank you so much, i will check on that.

Comment: Thank you very very much for all your help, it perfectly works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ATerry** - Ideally you would use some flavor of a collection instead of a delimited string. You can split the string and check it more efficiently or do something ugly and slow like this `i=>mylist.Any(t=>t == i.Divisions || i.Divisions.Contains(t + ",") || i.Divisions.EndsWith("," + t))`